# Emacs: how to rename a directory in dired-mode?

Tags: emacs, rename, dired

In Emacs, how does one rename a directory in dired-mode?

Comment: Nominating the question for re-opening, now that hetre has simplified/clarified the text.

Comment: @phils I would agree, this is a helpful question (and answer)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In dired, if you select a file and type 'R', you'll get a prompt under the modeline which will guide you through renaming the file. This works for files in general, including directories.

Comment: Working for me now. Thank you. Just yesterday, i could have sworn that I have tried everything.

Answer (score 7):

In general to explore dired-mode you can use `C-h m` and will get a useful summary 
for example :

- Type u to Unmark a file or all files of an inserted subdirectory.
- Type DEL to back up one line and unmark or unflag.
- Type x to delete    (eXecute) the files flagged 'D'.
- Type RET to Find the current line's    file   (or dired it in another buffer, if it is a directory).
- Type o    to find file or dired directory in Other window.
- Type i to Insert a    subdirectory in this buffer.
- **Type R to Rename a file or move the marked files to another directory.**
- Type C to Copy files.
- Type s to toggle Sorting by    name/date or change the `ls' switches.
- Type g to read all currently    expanded directories aGain.   This retains all marks and hides    subdirs again that were hidden before. Use `SPC' and`DEL' to move    down and up by lines.